# Как определить библиотеку для неоднозначного метода?

Tags: c#, методы, библиотеки

Ошибка: `неоднозначный вызов следующих методов или свойств: "AngleSharp.Text.CharExtensions.IsDigit(char)" и "Titanium.TypesFuncs.IsDigit(char)"`
PS: на самом деле, аргументы функции `IsDigit` – `this char`, а не `char`.

Я понимаю что происходит – у меня в библиотеке Titanium и в сторонней библиотеке AngleSharp имеется один и тот же метод (который, впринципе, выполняет одну и тоже и довольно очевидную вещь. Почему его только в язык не добавили, непонятно). Как сказать компилятору, что я во всем коде хочу использовать метод одной конкретной библиотеки?
Что-то вроде `using IsDigit = Titanium.TypesFuncs.IsDigit`?

Comment: Или using, или полный путь

Comment: Так а как с помощью using правильно это сделать? Полный путь указать проблематично, так как это функция `IsDigit(this char)`, да и не хотелось бы в любом случае

Comment: Можете использовать псевдоним `using IsDigit = Titanium.TypesFuncs.IsDigit`, а можете `using Titanium.TypesFuncs`. Область директивы using ограничена файлом, в котором она находится.

Comment: `Почему его только в язык не добавили, непонятно` .... `char.IsDigit(...)` ?

Comment: Добавили. [Char.IsDigit()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: `Полный путь указать проблематично` в чем проблема указать `Titanium.TypesFuncs.IsDigit(char)` ?

Comment: Ау, я же сказал, что там THIS char. Laukhin Andrey, сравните C#-вский `char.IsDigit(c)` и библиотечный `c.IsDigit()` – второй намного удобнее и понятнее. И почему его только в язык не добавили, а неудобный вариант оставили

Comment: `using IsDigit = Titanium.TypesFuncs.IsDigit` не работает, потому что IsDigit – не тип, а метод.
А `using static Titanium.TypesFuncs;` никак не исправляет ошибку. Да и не должен – конфликт по прежнему существует

Comment: `второй намного удобнее и понятнее` - А что вам мешает сделать это самостоятельно, если "удобней"? Например `public static bool IsDigit(this value) => char.IsDigit(value);`, все, одна строка, используете дальше как и сказали (`char.IsDigit()`). Просто это не всем нужно, зачастую достаточно простой проверки, это не тот инструментарий, который используется везде и всегда. Я даже больше скажу, обычно это используется в `LINQ`, а там это вовсе все опускается до `var result = "dar23g1".Where(char.IsDigit);`.

Comment: Касательно вашей проблемы, я бы сказал, что у вас проблема в структуре проекта, ибо как назвать то, что один и тот же код есть в разных `namespace`, которые вы используете? Ну а так, у вас несколько решений: 1. Сделать свой метод расширения, который будет ссылаться на один из нужных. 2. Писать полный путь (`Titanium.TypesFuncs.IsDigit(...)`), сократить это при помощи `Alias` (`using Ext = Titanium.TypesFuncs` и далее `Ext.IsDigit(...)`). 3. Убрать лишние `namespace`...

Comment: EvgeniyZ, этот метод есть в сторонней библиотеке, и этот же метод есть и в моей библиотеке. Я не всегда буду подключать обе эти библиотеки, поэтому я и не могу удалить аналогичный метод из своей. Касательно `Ext.IsDigit(...)`, то ещё раз повторюсь, что аргумент этой функции – `THIS char`, то есть, использовать я его буду как `SomeChar.IsDigit()`

Comment: `А что вам мешает сделать это самостоятельно, если "удобней"` – я это и сделал в своей библиотеке

Comment: @Титан `THIS char` - это называется "метод расширения", это обычный метод, который можно вызывать и как обычный. Я не вижу в этом каких-либо проблем, ну не будет у вас `SomeChar.IsDigit()`, будет `Ext.IsDigit(SomeChar)`, что, многое потеряли? `Я не всегда буду подключать обе эти библиотеки, поэтому я и не могу удалить аналогичный метод из своей.` - как это связано? "не буду подключать, из-за этого и не смогу удалить", это ваша библиотека, вы сами ей задали конфликтное имя, поменяйте просто его, да и радуйтесь жизни. P.S. Обращение на SO идет через `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попробовал сделать подобный проект. Если using объявить внутри namespace, то ошибки не возникает:

```
using System;
using AngleSharp.Text;


namespace CustomExtensions
{
    public static class CharExtension
    {
        public static bool IsDigit(this char c)
        {
            return Char.IsDigit(c);
        }
    }
}

namespace Experim
{
    using static CustomExtensions.CharExtension;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char a = '5';
            Console.WriteLine(a.IsDigit());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё же, мне бы хотелось бы сделать это для отдельного метода, а не для всего класса, но ваш ответ всё равно решает мою проблему, спасибо!

Comment: `Всё же, мне бы хотелось бы сделать это для отдельного метода` - документация обнадеживает. Чтобы уменьшить подобные коллизии в будущем можете в своей библиотеке разбивать пространство имен. В частности, для одного метода - отдельный namespace. Тогда это будет эквивалентно using для одного метода. А что поделать...